# I haven't been long as

Tags: prepositional-phrases, time

Imagine that I'm talking to my friend. That's the dialog is very casual. Can I say

> I haven't been long as a programmer.

in the sense that I work as a a programmer not very far. Is it suitable for informal discussion?

Comment: I think in any case you should replace I with it..Because "you" cannot be long but a date or a span of time can be..so I think you can say " it hasn't been a long time since I started to work as a programmer" but I am not sure how can we make it informal because I am not native speaker of English

Comment: The idiomatic standard form is *I haven't been a programmer long*. It's also perfectly acceptable to say ***for** long*, but in practice people usually don't include the superfluous preposition, regardless of whether the state being referred to is a noun *(a programmer)* or an adjective *(married)*.

Answer (score 3):

> I haven't been long as a programmer

This sounds like you are not very tall when you are a programmer, or something. The correct idiom is

> I haven't been a programmer **for long**.

Comment: Yes, ***but***... if you compare 5 hits in Google Books for [*I haven't been a member **for** long*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I+haven%27t+been+a+member+for+long%22) against [34 hits](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I+haven%27t+been+a+member+long%22) for the "prepositionless" version, it's clear that the idiomatic standard is *not* to include the preposition. That's even clearer if you run the same check on an adjectival context like *I haven't been **married** long*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, agreed about the optional preposition... but the word order?  **long** following the adjective is maybe six times more common than **long** following **been**. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=been+long+married%2C+been+married+long&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbeen%20long%20married%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbeen%20married%20long%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Java It seems very strange to me (a non native speaker) that **long** is used for human height. I don't think I have found similar usage earlier, so asking you if this usage is at all correct.

Comment: @Man_From_India, It's not common but it is possible. There are songs by Robert Blackwell and later the Beatles called "Long Tall Sally". The name was adopted by a women's fashion chain store for tall women. There is also a pirate in Robert Louis Stevenson's book "Treasure Island" called Long John Silver. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_John_Silver

Comment: @Java: I think the "proper" place for **long** has always been *adjacent* to the relevant noun/adjective (immediately before *or* after). Have a look at [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hadn%27t+long+been+married%2Chadn%27t+been+long+married%2Chadn%27t+been+married+long&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=50&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chad%20not%20long%20been%20married%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chad%20not%20been%20long%20married%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chad%20not%20been%20married%20long%3B%2Cc0),..

Comment: ...where two centuries ago, *hadn't been **married long*** was the least favoured, and *hadn't been **long married*** ruled the roost. Now it's the opposite - but interestingly, *one* century ago, at the transition point where both were equally popular, the *most* popular version was the one with **long** moved further away (to before **been**) as *hadn't **long been** married*. But people must have not really liked it, since for *most* of the entire chart period they were obviously keen to use *either* alternative that would keep **long** close to a *semantic* rather than *syntactic* element.

Answer (score -2):

If you wish to emphasize on the time period, it would be best to use

> I haven't spent a lot of time programming.

Otherwise the construct mentioned before is also great.

Comment: That suggests to me that it's something you do regularly, but a little at a time. Maybe you do it as a hobby- half an hour a day-  rather than working as a programmer. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/spend